# Californium CoAP Server Error on addEndpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, coap

I am trying one of example CoAP server program from
https://github.com/eclipse/californium.core/tree/master/cf-helloworld-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/examples/HelloWorldServer.java

I have used library CoAP from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.californium/californium-core/1.0.1

When I run below code to addEndpoints, I get an exception:

```
 private void addEndpoints() {
        for (InetAddress addr : EndpointManager.getEndpointManager().getNetworkInterfaces()) {
            // only binds to IPv4 addresses and localhost
            if (addr instanceof Inet4Address || addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                System.out.println("addr: "+addr.toString());
                InetSocketAddress bindToAddress = new InetSocketAddress(addr, COAP_PORT);
                System.out.println("bindToAddress: "+bindToAddress.toString());
                addEndpoint(new CoapEndpoint(bindToAddress));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the Exception:

Jan 20, 2016 3:24:58 PM org.eclipse.californium.core.network.config.NetworkConfig createStandardWithFile
INFO: Storing standard properties in file Californium.properties

> addr: /127.0.0.1 
>   bindToAddress: /127.0.0.1:5683

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/californium/elements/RawDataChannel
    at HelloWorldServer.addEndpoints(HelloWorldServer.java:53)
    at HelloWorldServer.main(HelloWorldServer.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.californium.elements.RawDataChannel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

> I see no file in GitHub Source
>   org/eclipse/californium/elements/RawDataChannel.java is that is the
>   problem !?

I tried to clean and rebuild the project still same issue.
Created project again, don't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried with other library ch.ethz.inf.vs  californium, but having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is old, though maybe the answer will be useful for someone..

There was lack of element-connector library.
I'd recommend to use Maven and add californium as a dependency to pom.xml