# Unable to Setup CoAP Server using Californium Java Library

Tags: java, eclipse, coap

I am trying to setup CoAP Server using Java library from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.californium/californium-core/1.0.1

```
public class HelloWorldServer extends CoapServer {

    private static final int COAP_PORT = 5683; 
    /*
     * Application entry point.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // create server
            HelloWorldServer server = new HelloWorldServer();
            // add endpoints on all IP addresses
            server.addEndpoint(new CoAPEndpoint(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", COAP_PORT)));
            server.start();

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to initialize server: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

adding endpoints to server causing below Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/californium/elements/RawDataChannel   at
>   com.landisgyr.chardonnay.HelloWorldServer.main(HelloWorldServer.java:35)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.californium.elements.RawDataChannel   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 1 more

Is there anyone who go CoAP server working with Californium Java library ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Californium CoAP Server Error on addEndpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896969/californium-coap-server-error-on-addendpoints)

Answer (score 2):

You need to import [element-connector](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.californium/element-connector) into your Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some parts of the project are missing.

Here is a step-by-step tutorial to run the CoAP HelloWorldServer.

**Requirements** : Eclipse (+ Egit & Maven Integration Extenstions) , Git , Maven

1. Open Terminal and execute following commands:

`sudo git clone https://github.com/eclipse/californium.core.git`

```
sudo mvn clean install
```

2. Open Eclipse and import the Maven Project
3. After import launch the "HelloWorldServer.java". If anything done correctly it should work.

[Endpoint started and working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOESI.png)

4. To test if the resource is avaiable i recommend the Firefox extension "Cupper" which is able to speak CoAP. You just need to open the following URI: coap://localhost:5683